# Is there any way to post Facebook status using ContactsContent Provider?

Tags: android, facebook

I am using QuickContactBadge widget in my application.I want to post facebook status message using contactsContentProvider.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The [contract between ContactsContentProvider and applications](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) has no information about facebook. And considering the hate between facebook and Google, it will probably not for a long time.